# Is it possible to change Windows 10 taskbar icon (Windows logo) in a native way?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons

**Is it possible to change Windows 10 taskbar icon without using external tools?** This Windows logo:

[image: Windows 10 logo]

Where is the HKEY value? Is even more simple?

Also I am curious wether that icon is actually a bitmap image or vector image.

I searched on Internet and couldn't find anything, perhaps I am searching wrong.

Comment: Try Resource Hacker (regular app to examine icons). Look in shell32.dll.mun  (read the app documentation).  I do not think you can change it (copyright by Microsoft) but this is where to look.

Comment: @John Thanks for the feedback! I updated the question, I would prefer to see the process without using external tools.

Comment: I updated my post to answer your edited question.

Comment: The start menu icon cannot be changed without writing software to do so. Simply replacing the icon, within a compiled binary with another, isn’t possible for a lot of reasons. The most obvious one that is explained in a half of a sentence, it would be immediately be patched back to the original file, once Microsoft updated the file. Programs like Start10 and StartIsBack offer this feature, but in both cases, the original start menu is still there but hidden

Answer (score 0):

The start button icon in all recent Windows (Vista forward) (if not all Microsoft Windows) is a Microsoft emblem and so protected by copyright.

So I do not think you can change it and it certainly would not be appropriate to change it.

And per your recent Question revision, there is no native way to change the icon.

See here for more information.

[Start Icon copyright](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264705/are-default-program-icons-protected-by-copyright#:%7E:text=Yes%2C%20the%20icons%20are%20copyrighted%2C%20in%20this%20case%20by%20Microsoft.&text=%3E%20Icons%20are%20not%20to%20be,%22artwork%22%20or%20design%20elements.)

There are replacement apps that use different icons (classic start type apps) but the original icon (Microsoft's) is not changed.

Comment: It seems that the icons have copyright, but what are you based on to affirm that the Windows icon cannot be changed? In fact Windows allows us to change some icons, but why not that particular icon? Do you have an updated Microsoft response?

Comment: The start menu, screen, or whatever you want to call it can most certainly be changed otherwise programs like Start10, Start11, StartIsBack, StartAllBack, and Classic Shell would not be possible. [This](http://www.startisback.com/img/promo3.jpg) illustrates my point

Comment: I clarified my post to say that replacement icons exist but the Microsoft icon is still there. The OP was looking for a native to Microsoft Windows way to change the icon.